# How to read all files of a directory in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to read all the files of a directory and it have to be in Haskell but I didn`t find any material about read all files
Can someone help me?

Comment: Funny, I had a similar problem when I tried to search for "simulate plane engine" - no functions found!  More seriously though, if you're an experienced programmer then you know such a function is a composition of several more basic ones which you should be looking for (on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle), the search engine for Haskell functions).  If you aren't a more experienced programmer then that is exactly the sort of thing you should put in a question, the more context the more people can help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3areadFile) to read a file, and [`getDirectoryContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/latest/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v%3agetDirectoryContents) to list the files in a directory.

Comment: note: `listDirectory` is the same as `getDirectoryContents`, except that is doesn't give you `.` and `..`

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/directory-1.0.1.1/System-Directory.html#v%3AgetDirectoryContents, which will list all the files in a directory for you. Then, you can use the standard Haskell IO functions to read the file. Add more to the question if you need anything more specific.